# django rest_framework different update based on a model field and user rights

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

django rest-framework

this is a snipnet of my model:

```
Class myModel(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS, default=STATUS[0][0], null=True)
    status_update_information=models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='Mymodel')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

the status field can have 3 value: pending, confirmed and rejected.
Only the owner or the administrator can update the object but I need to insert some constraint:

- only the admin can change the status field and  must provide some extra information stored in an other field (status_update_information)
- if the status is confirmed only some fields can be updated ( description )
- if the status is not confirmed the owner can update all field (obviously not status or status_update_information)

I also need to perform other operation when the administratop update the status field (notify the creator)

in order to manage  that I create three different serializer

One for create the model instance

```
 class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        read_only_fields = ('creator', 'status', 'created_at','updated_at')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super(MyModelSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return super(MyModelSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

One for update the model if the status is confirmed

```
class MyModelConfirmedUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields =['title',  'description']
```

and one for the adminstrator

```
class MyModelAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        read_only_fields =('creator', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super(MyModelAdminSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        status = validated_data.get('status')
        if status != str(instance.status):
            if not validated_data.get('status_update_reason'):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(' status update require motivations')
            else:
                nofitycreator(instance)
        return super(MyModelAdminSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

and override the get_serializer_class method of the Apiview

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    serializer_class = self.serializer_class
    if self.request.method == 'PUT' or self.request.method == 'PATCH':
        if self.request.user.is_staff or self.request.user.is_superuser:
            serializer_class = MyModelAdminSerializer
        else:
            try:
                if self.get_object().status == Initiative.STATUS[1][0]:
                    serializer_class = MyModelConfirmedUpdateSerializer
            except:
                pass
    return serializer_class
```

Is there  some smart solution?

How can handle the partial update of the status field in order to be sure that the status_update_information are provided?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I've been trying for more than a week to have some more complex logic like this in DRF, but it seems there's absolutely zero resources or tools from DRF itself to make this easy and with little code. Answers to this question would be very much appreciated! :)